# Adding new parameter to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, undefined-behavior

What do I pass in for the existing arguments that have no value, undefined or null?

Existing function foo(a, b) is called like foo(1) and foo(23, "hi").  After adding a new parameter, it's foo(a, b, c) and I want to change foo(1) to be foo(1, undefined, 3.2) or foo(1, null, 3.2).

Does null 'looking better' override the concern that existing code may already expect the second param to be undefined in some cases?

Comment: If you don't change the original calls the `undefined` is implicitly passed for the arguments you don't specify.

Comment: @GregBurghardt We are aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming ES5**

You should switch to passing objects to your function:

```js
var foo = function(options){
    var first = options.first;
    var second = options.second;
    var third = options.third; 
    ...
}
```

This way, you have a much cleaner Interface `foo({first:"Test", third:"Test3"})`

You name the parameters, you want to set explicitely. This has the upside of no necessity to remember in which sequence the parameters have to be called and to remember whether `null` or `undefined` was the 2nd parameter and you see what maps to what.

**Assuming ES6+**

This becomes in ES6 [parameter context matching](http://es6-features.org/#ParameterContextMatching):

```js
const foo = ({first, second, third})=>{...}

foo({first:"Test", third:"Test3"})
```

There is a bit of implicit destructuring "magic":

```js
foo({first:"Test", third:"Test3"})
```

behaves like

```js
foo(obj)
```

and

```js
const foo = ({first, second, third})=>{...}
```

is equivalent to:

```js
const foo = (options)=>{
 const {first, second, third} = options;
 ...
}
```

which is equivalent to the **ES5** solution with [object matching](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingShorthandNotation) (a subkind of destructuring) added.

And object matching behaves like the **ES5** solution above.

---

**tl;dr**

Recommendation: Refactor your code, avoiding positional arguments at all.

Comment: +1 for Refactoring, however it might be infeasible to refactor an already existing function if it is used a lot. If that is the case, I’d write a differently named function for the new use case (i.e. with three arguments, or with an argument object), and delegate calls to the old, two-parameter function to the new one.

Comment: @bleistift2 yes and no. Of course you are right it might be infeasible under certain circumstances. OTOH we are in the age of ever smarter IDEs  which make it cheap to do that - supposed you have a good testsuite it should be a no brainer.

Comment: It is totally ok to vote an answer down. But I would encourage people to do so openly and give reasons of why they downvoted it. And especically in this case, where the answer is technical sound and elaborate. Without giving reasons it feels like backstabbing,